# Clock variant of the Second-Chance page-replacement Algorithm vs. standard Second-Chance Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, operating-systems, memory-management, paging

A sample question for my upcoming Operating Systems exam is:

> Under which circumstances would the clock variant [of the second-chance algorithm] be preferred over the standard second-chance algorithm and why.

I was under the impression that the clock variant is **always** preferred. Am I missing something? Are there *specific* circumstances (hardware-related perhaps) where the clock variant would be preferred? Equally, is the standard algorithm ever preferred?

A similar question was asked and answered [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29092/whats-the-difference-between-clock-and-second-chance-page-replacement-algorithm) but it didn't mention any benefits

*EDIT: A comment from @Wandering below led me to ask my lecturer for more clarification, and he is **not referring to the two-handed clock variant**.*

Comment: Perhaps they are asking the difference between _two-handed_ clock and standard second-chance?  If that is the case then you should look for access patterns where LRU does particularly poorly.

Comment: @WanderingLogic I have asked my Operating Systems lecturer this exact question, but he responded by saying that no, the question is about the traditional clock variant; being an eccentric man, he won't answer my questions directly so I haven't managed to squeeze any more information out of him. Will update if I am able to clarify further.